# is it correct to use a DynamoDB scan operation with pagination instead of query with GSI, I need all the items from the table

Tags: pagination, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I read that dynamo db scan operation is slow when the data is large . but i want to know that, Having a scenario to extract all the items. Is it still preferred to avoid scan ?
considering indexes are not free and i need all the items from table, i am going for this approach.

1. Please suggest if their is any problem by choosing scan operation  ?
2. why only scan has parallel scan option, is query parallel by default ?
3. if i use query operation with pagination will it run sequential or parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need all items, then Scan() is perfectly fine.

Just realize that DDB

- only returns 1MB of data at a time, so you'll need to call in a loop using `ExclusiveStartKey` := `LastEvaluatedKey`
- Scan() can quickly consume your provisioned RCU, so watch for throttle errors and retry.

The recommendation against Scan() is trying to use Scan() + filter in place of Query() for a subset of records.  Scan() always reads the full table.

Also note that from a performance standpoint, Scan() supports [parallel scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-TotalSegments).

> **TotalSegments**
> For a parallel Scan request, TotalSegments represents
> the total number of segments into which the Scan operation will be
> divided. The value of TotalSegments corresponds to the number of
> application workers that will perform the parallel scan. For example,
> if you want to use four application threads to scan a table or an
> index, specify a TotalSegments value of 4.

But again, if using provisioned reads...a parallel scan will eat up RCU quickly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Charles. Can you help me by sharing an example of using parallel scan in a lambda function using node js ?

Comment: If I use query with GSI , will it also have performance issue when the table grows?

Comment: Query can only access data from one partition at a time.  If you need all items, scan is the right solution.